# Likelihood Function vs. Log-Likelihood function do their plots look different?

Tags: r, distributions, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

### Background:

I am trying to understand (via plotting) the difference between **(a)** ***Likelihood Function***, and **(b)** ***Log-Likelihood function*** from 3 data points (i.e., 250, 265, 259) believed to have come from a normal density ($\mu$ of this normal is to be estimated).

### Question:

I am wondering **which version(s) of the plots below (*in R code*) that I have tried below** accurately give(s) me the **(a)** and **(b)** as described in the *background* above?

**Version # 1:**

```
Likelihood = function(x) dnorm(250, x, 2)*dnorm(265, x, 2)*dnorm(259, x, 2)

curve(Likelihood, from = 250, to = 266)
```

**Version # 2:**

```
curve(Likelihood, from = 250, to = 266, ylog = T) # Notice the ylog = T
```

**Version # 3:**

```
curve(Likelihood, from = 250, to = 266, log = "y") # Notice the log = "y"
```

**Version # 4:**

```
Likelihood2 = function(x) dnorm(250, x, 2, log = T)+dnorm(265, x, 2, log = T)+dnorm(259, x, 2, log = T)

curve(Likelihood2, from = 250, to = 266)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1 is the likelihood. That's correct. You can multiply together individual/marginal likelihoods $f(x_i;\mu)$ if you're assuming your data points are independent. In other words $f(x_1,x_2,x_3;\mu) = f(x_1;\mu)f(x_2;\mu)f(x_3;\mu)$.

Version 4 is correct as well. Taking the log of the above equation gives you 
$$
\log f(x_1,x_2,x_3;\mu) = \log f(x_1;\mu) + \log f(x_2;\mu) + \log f(x_3;\mu).
$$

Versions 2 and 3 (edit: 3 is good actually) are incorrect but are unnecessary because your fourth version works. Moreover you seem to be asking us to read the documentation of `curve` for you, which is off topic here. Here's a related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052987/plotting-logscale-in-rs-curve

Comment: @parvinkarimi yes they will be different in shape, and yes usually people use the natural log because a lot of probability distributions have $e$ in their pmf or pdf.

Comment: @parvinkarimi the function might be using base ten then. Use the change of base formulas for logarithms to check.